# How to remove last saved cheche element click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How many times I click the buttons, it will get all clicked count, and put that elements on my table tr!
 I want to for each button click once time and added to my table tr without duplicated data!
 if you didn't here the example

```js
$("body").on("click", "button.list_of_drugs_main", function() {
  var l_drug_id = $(this).attr("data-did");
  var l_drug_generic_name = $(this).text().trim();

  for (var i = 0; i < $(".pt_list_table_tbody tr").length; i++) {
    var ef = $(".pt_list_table_tbody tr")[i];
    if ($(ef).hasClass("drug_id_" + l_drug_id)) {
      //console.log(1);
    } else {
      //console.log(0);
      $(".pt_list_table_tbody").append("<tr class=' drug_id_" + l_drug_id + "'><td>" + l_drug_id +
        "</td><td>" + l_drug_generic_name + "</td></tr>");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='1'>Drug 1</button><br>
<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='2'>Drug 2</button><br>
<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='3'>Drug 3</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Drug Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="pt_list_table_tbody">
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to: when I Click the button/s add|append button/s details into my table rows without duplicated rows! thanks

Comment: So are you expecting that if you click 'Drug 1' multiple times, then you should only see 1 row added to the table? Or should there be a 'counter' column? The expected output is not clear.

Comment: No, I mean: If I click 'Drug 1' button, add the Drug 1 Button data-did and Drug 1 Button text(). As I showed in my example... but now when I click 'Drug 1' Button then click 'Drug 2' Button it will put 3 rows and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `if/else` logic. For every row that doesn't already have the same drug ID, you're appending the new row.

You should just search the table to see if the row already exists. If it doesn't exist, add it.

```js
$("body").on("click", "button.list_of_drugs_main", function() {
  var l_drug_id = $(this).attr("data-did");
  var l_drug_generic_name = $(this).text().trim();
  if ($(`.pt_list_table_tbody tr.drug_id_${l_drug_id}`).length == 0) {
    $(".pt_list_table_tbody").append("<tr class=' drug_id_" + l_drug_id + "'><td>" + l_drug_id +
      "</td><td>" + l_drug_generic_name + "</td></tr>");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='1'>Drug 1</button><br>
<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='2'>Drug 2</button><br>
<button type="button" class="list_of_drugs_main" data-did='3'>Drug 3</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Drug Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="pt_list_table_tbody">
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```